# Django auto_now what method is used?

Tags: python, django, datetime

What method django uses to populate `DateTime` field with `auto_now` option? Looking at the db, I see this format:

```
2014-12-01 03:20:59.226-08
```

I want to get current time in this format in django shell. What should I import and use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just `datetime.datetime.now()`.

Comment: But that gives me this in shell: `datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 10, 3, 31, 24, 969000)`

Comment: Can I print it as string like the one above?

Comment: Yes you can. Did you try using `print`?

Comment: DAMN. I thought shell would print it automatically. Thanks. I'll accept.

Comment: If you're interested, the shell uses `repr()` to display values, rather than `str()`.

Comment: Great info. Thanks Daniel.